# how can I multiply a and b with my recursive method?

Tags: java

I can not multiply my method with a and b ; I got error:

Multiple markers at this line
    - a cannot be resolved to a 
     variable
    - b cannot be resolved to a 
     variable

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Terminal.printLine("Please enter n , a and b ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            Terminal.printLine(i + "," + recursiv(n));

    }

    public static long recursiv(int n) {

        if (n >= 0 && n <= 2)
            return 1;

        else
            return a*recursiv(n - 2) + b*recursiv(n - 3);

    }

}
```

Comment: you'll have to pass `a` and `b` to your `recursiv` method in order to use them.

Comment: `a` and `b` are local variables in `main`. `recursiv` cannot see them.

Comment: And please show us this "error" you are talking about.

Comment: @Lutzi: "Multiple markers at this line - a cannot be resolved to a variable - b cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Well you have your answer : your method cannot see `a` and `b`, as Eran and Thilo said.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate what `n` is supposed to be? In your title you say you just want to multiply `a` and `b` so what is the point of that third variable?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I have a sequence, which is described recursively as follows:
pi =1( for 0 ≤ i ≤ 2)
pi = a * p(i-2) + b * p(i-3) for i> 2

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Terminal.printLine("Please enter n , a and b ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        Terminal.printLine(i + "," + recursiv(n,a,b));

}

public static long recursiv(int n, int a, int b) {

    if (n >= 0 && n <= 2)
        return 1;

    else
        return a*recursiv(n - 2) + b*recursiv(n - 3);

}
```

}

Comment: That will not work as the recursiv calls inside the method have the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

make a and b global variables,

like this

```
 public class Main {

static int a = 0;
static int b = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Terminal.printLine("Please enter n , a and b ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        Terminal.printLine(i + "," + recursiv(n));

}

public static long recursiv(int n) {

    if (n >= 0 && n <= 2)
        return 1;

    else
        return a*recursiv(n - 2) + b*recursiv(n - 3);

}

}
```

now you should be able to call these anywhere in the class without passing them to methods.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Formula & Rules**

> pi =1( for 0 ≤ i ≤ 2).
>
> pi = a * p(i-2) + b * p(i-3) for i> 2 ... where:
>
> - a and b are initializers of the sequence and ∈ Z.
> - i ≤ n and n ∈ N ∪ {0}.

---

**Implementation**

```
public class Sequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter n, a and b");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
                System.out.println("i= " + i + "\tpi= " + result(a,b,i));
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }

    static long result(int a, int b, int n) {
        if(n >= 0 && n <= 2) return 1;

        return a * result(a , b, n-2) + b * result(a, b, n-3);
    }
}
```

---

**TEST**

**Input**

```
n = 25, a = 5, b = 10.
```

**Output**

```
i= 1    pi= 1
i= 2    pi= 1
i= 3    pi= 15
i= 4    pi= 15
i= 5    pi= 85
i= 6    pi= 225
i= 7    pi= 575
i= 8    pi= 1975
i= 9    pi= 5125
i= 10   pi= 15625
i= 11   pi= 45375
i= 12   pi= 129375
i= 13   pi= 383125
i= 14   pi= 1100625
i= 15   pi= 3209375
i= 16   pi= 9334375
i= 17   pi= 27053125
i= 18   pi= 78765625
i= 19   pi= 228609375
i= 20   pi= 664359375
i= 21   pi= 1930703125
i= 22   pi= 5607890625
i= 23   pi= 16297109375
i= 24   pi= 47346484375
i= 25   pi= 137564453125
```